# Windows Server 2008 - Create Windows Explorer Link that opens to C:

Tags: windows-server-2008

I'd like to create a shortcut that I can put on my quick-launch bar that opens to C: or My Computer. What is the correct way to do this in Windows Server 2008?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click the desktop, select New> Shortcut, type "explorer.exe c:" (without the quotes)  in the location box (or browse to the C: drive), click next, type a name or leave it as is, click finish, drag the shortcut to your taskbar.

Comment: Bah! You get all the easy ones. =)

Comment: I won't deny it...

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Here's a similar question, with a twist: http://serverfault.com/questions/68575/windows-serv-2008-id-like-to-create-a-windows-explorer-shortcut-that-opens-to